# Watir webdriver: uploading files isn't working in SAFARI browser?

Tags: safari, watir, watir-webdriver, safaridriver

I am trying to attach file to upload with form in safari browser. Element is searchable but file is not attached.

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" maxlength="255" onchange="copyfile();" style="width: 59px; ">
```

using following command

```
b.file_field( :id=>"file" ).set "/Users/......../Desktop/abc"
returns
=> "/Users/......../Desktop/abc"
```

but file not populate in file field

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you really using safariwatir ruby gem? Or are you using watir-webdriver gem to drive Safari?

Comment: Željko I am using watir-webdriver and built safari extension to run safari driver.

Answer (score 3):

[Issue 4220: The SafariDriver does not support file uploads](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4220)